# how to create space between the images?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am getting my head around bootstrap 3 , html5 and css3. Trying to build a page containing a few images:

```css
.front {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
img {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Question: how can I display the images adding some space (margin, padding) between them? I tried to set the margin/padding for the img css rule:**

here is a link to the code:https://github.com/dimster2013/soccerapp/commit/f9bde7aafbcffffabc9b034b66ee25440ea5f6aa

Comment: Please post a minimal sample of your code. The link to the github page is a huge thing with hundreds of lines where we’d look for a simple `margin` rule. These three CSS lines could have been included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add a margin to div (col-lg-3) containing the images - this rule could look similar to this:

```
.col-lg-3 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

That will add space between the images as you asked for. It will still display all images underneath each other, not on the same line; other answers to your question explain why.

Comment: Why do you post this comment? I think it actually does answer the question, even though it would have been better to elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add Below CSS

.col-sm-3 .front img {
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px !important;
  width:100%!important;
}

.col-sm-3{
padding:0px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: running the code snippet moves all images in 1 column only?

Comment: you need to place this html where bootstrap classes are embedded to html page. Also add custom css provided in answer i.e. -->                .col-sm-3 .front img {
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px !important;
  width:100%!important;
}

.col-sm-3{
padding:0px!important;
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at your markup, you are using div elements with class `col-lg-3` in which house your img tags.

By placing:

```
.col-lg-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

on this div class instead, it should work for you.

The reason your images are displaying one per line is due to div elements being `display: block` declaration by default. Overriding this by setting `inline-block` would allow multiple images per line (if screen width permits).

A quick demo would be:

```css
img {
  height: 300px;
}
.col-lg-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="front">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRE1_PJ6L1IQVa2v6Xd1G7vypRQbQmCKGTq0TkMNJmMHFPm-hvKYA" alt="messi" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```